# Update pointer value in struct automatically

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to automatically update pointer value inside a structure when memory allocation goes later? Please, look at the code.

```
struct S {void *ptr;};

void *p;
struct S ST= {p};

int main() {
    p = new int;
    void* b = ST.ptr; // b should be the same as p
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're in C++, you could use a reference to the pointer.  If you're in C, you could use a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: You can change the order of actions, or which part of the code is responsible for allocating. Or, you can add another layer of indirection. But as always it's a good idea to look at *the real problem*, not the imagined technical solution to that problem. Which means, adding another layer of indirection, which comes at a cost, is probably not a good idea. It's a technical solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply hold an indirection:

#### C++:

```
struct S
{
    void*&  ptr; // ptr is now a reference to a pointer. Drawback: Has to be initialized.
};
```

This can be used as follows:

```
S s = {p};
```

But references as members are a controversial subject. In this case, the other way of indirection may be better:

#### C:

Maybe the new in your snippet was just for explanatory purposes, and you work with C (the elaborate type specifier in your code supports that argument).

```
struct S
{
    void**  ptr; // ptr is now a pointer to a pointer. Drawback: Can be zero.
};
```

In this case, you initialize `ptr` with the address of the pointer it should refer to:

```
struct S s = {&p}; // I don't know about list-initialization in C, so i'll stick to this
```

Subsequently, when dereferencing it you'll get an lvalue to `p`.

For differences between references and pointers, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

And also don't forget about [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one). Maybe [shared ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852710/single-vs-shared-ownership-meaning) is what you're looking for.